# results are not the same between google places API and Google maps site

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I'm working on this for 2 days and I do'nt have idea about what's happening.

I'm looking for Phamacy near an address on Google Maps
farmácia loc: R. Manoel Bandeira, 324-490, Embu - São Paulo, 06846-570, Brazil

As you can see there are a lot of pharmacies nearby 5 kilometers

When trying to do it on my site by using the google places api. The result is = NOTHING.
Follow the code
Any thoughts?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false&language=se"></script>
<script>

function init() {

const location=new google.maps.LatLng(-23.6334282, -46.8739405);
const radius = 5000;

// Make map
var mapOptions = {
center: location,
zoom: 11,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

// Make a circle
var circOptions={
center: location,
radius: radius,
map: map
};
circle = new google.maps.Circle(circOptions);  

// Get shops in radius
service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
var request={                                               //my request
location: location,
radius: radius,
types: ["pharmacy"]
};

service.search(request, function (results, status){
if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK){
for (var i= 0, result; result=results[i]; i++) {     //add markers
distance=google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(location, result.geometry.location);
if (distance>radius)
continue;

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
map: map,
position: result.geometry.location,
reference: result.reference
});
}
}
});

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

</script>

<style>#map {height: 500px;width: 500px;}</style>
</head>
<body><div id="map"></div></body>
</html>
```

Comment: [This](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_10minuteDriveG.html?q=pharmacy&address=-23.6334,-46.8739) seems to find it.

Comment: Thank you !!! Now it's working. Is there a way to sort the results using the option rankBy: google.maps.places.RankBy.DISTANCE. I want to get the nearest locations (I don't need the radius). Is it possible?